# Live server image loading problems with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, http-status-code-404, liveserver

I've created an image array and a function the generates a random image on a button click.

When I use live server to run the function, some images will be produced but not others.

On inspection in Chrome I get the message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". and this message applies to each image that could not be loaded. I've made notes of the JPG's that couldn't be loaded, and on a live server reload some of these images that couldn't be loaded are loaded(its a random function) and some that were loaded previously generate the 404 error.All images in the array check out OK.
Any help would be appreciated

```js
function randomImages(){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
    if(rnd == 0){
        rnd = 1;
    }

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src =myImages[rnd];
    
    var div = document.getElementById("flex-box-create");
    div.appendChild(image)
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if those images are displayed correctly when accessing them directly? Like typing url in browser?

Comment: I seem to have sorted it out. There was a "./" on the path of some of the images and it was these images that were not loading properly. I removed this an it all works now. Thanks for your help anyway